# Use regex on data and assign matches to new scope

Tags: regex, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

I'm having trouble finding any examples of this, but it doesn't seem like it should be too difficult.

Basically I have a $resource that returns JSON. In the **controller** I assign some different things to $scope from the data, for example:

```
$scope.stuff = data.index.stuff
```

Then I run ng-repeat on this data in the view.

What I would like to do is run a regex on 'data.index.stuff' and pull out the matches. Then I'd like to assign the matches to one scope variable, and the remainder to another scope variable. So given a regex like this:

```
/>>[0-9]{0,6}/g
```

and data like this:

```
>>4 this is some test data
```

I'd like to turn it into two variables like:

```
$scope.number = ">>4"

$scope.somedata = "this is some test data"
```

and allow the new data to be looped through via ng-repeat.

Thank you for looking!

Comment: I feel there are several questions in one. Are you asking us how to perform regex with javascript or how to use angularJS ?

Comment: No I know how to do regex in JS, I don't understand how to do it in a way where I can assign it to different $scope variables like I described. Unless I'm missing something really obvious (quite possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a gigantic pain but I finally got it working. I took the linky filter from the sanitize module and modified it into a directive. It basically turns a scope into two via regex on a certain pattern, as described in the OP. So I start with just scope.post.comment, extract my pattern and place it in another scope, and the remnants stay in comment.

```
app.directive('commentHandler', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        post: '=',
        thread: '='
      },
      templateUrl: "pages/comment.html",
      controller: function($scope, $sce, $sanitize) {
        re = /(>>(\d{1,4})).*/;

        raw = $scope.post.comment;
        html = [];
        quote = [];

        while (match = raw.match(re)) {
          url = match[2];
          i = match.index;
          addText(raw.substr(0, i));
          addLink(url, match[1]);
          raw = raw.substring(i + match[1].length);
        }
        addText(raw);
        $scope.post.comment = raw;
        $scope.post.quote = $sanitize(quote.join(''))

        function addText(text) {
          html.push(text);
        }

        function addLink(url, text) {
          quote.push('<a ');
          quote.push('href="');
          quote.push('post/' + $scope.thread.id + '/' + url);
          quote.push('">');
          quote.push(text);
          quote.push('</a>');
        }

      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following pattern:

```
/^(>>[0-9]{0,6}) (.*)$/gm
```

Comment: Thanks, the capturing groups make more sense. However I was more looking for how to add the resulting text to a $scope that can be looped with ng-repeat. Maybe the question is worded poorly.